# Get current location using Wi-Fi?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-location

How to get current location using [Wi-Fi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi) towers in iPhone without using GPS?

Actually I have an old [iPhone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone) which does not contain any GPS. So I want to find my current location using Wi-Fi or by using any other method.

Answer (score 11):

The location services within the iPhone OS do this automatically.  Just request the 'best accuracy' in your LocationManager and it will do the rest for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not all [Wi-Fi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi) zones will provide you with this though!